# Lost Internet connexion with Vagrant/Homestead launched

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I use VirtualBox to use the homestead of Laravel.

When I start my VM with `vagrant up`, just after, I lose my Internet connection...

Then I have to run `sudo service network-manager restart` to restart the service and get Internet connectivity back.

Do you have an ideas?

Comment: I thuink this bug come from a bad installation of Ubuntu / VirtualBox.. I am on Win8 now :'(

Comment: Having same problem on Windows 8.1. vagrant up and then theres some ubuntu downloading and saying no internet and whole computer doesnt have internet anymore.